# Memory leaks in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

Hi, guys! i'm newbie in iphone development. I have problems with the memory leak. I have such code.

```
do {

    int s = sqlite3_step(statement);
    switch (s) {
        case SQLITE_ROW:{

            Article *a = [[[Article alloc] init] autorelease];
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                const char *columnName = sqlite3_column_name(statement, i);
                if(strncmp(columnName, "title", strlen("title")) == 0){
                    const char* colStr = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
                    if(colStr != NULL)
                        a.title = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString: colStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
                    continue;
                }
                if(strncmp(columnName, "author", strlen("author")) == 0){
                    const char* colStr = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
                    if(colStr != NULL)
                        a.author = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:colStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
                    continue;
                }
                if(strncmp(columnName, "description", strlen("description")) == 0){
                    const char* colStr = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
                    if(colStr != NULL)
                        a.description = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:colStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
                    continue;
                }
                if(strncmp(columnName, "link", strlen("link")) == 0){
                    const char* colStr = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
                    if (colStr) 
                        a.link = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:colStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
                    continue;
                }
                if(strncmp(columnName, "imageUrl", strlen("imageUrl")) == 0){
                    const char* colStr = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
                    if (colStr)
                        a.imageUrl = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:colStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
                    continue;
                }
                if(strncmp(columnName, "pubDate", strlen("pubDate")) == 0){
                    const char* colStr = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
                    if(colStr)
                        a.pubDate = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:colStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
                    continue;
                }
            }
            [array insertObject:a atIndex:0];
        }
        break;
        case SQLITE_DONE:
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            dataForReadingAvailable = NO;
            break;
        default:{
            NSLog(@"getArticlesForFeed:sqlite3_step failed.Error:%s",sqlErrMsg);
            return nil;
        }
        break;
    }   
}while(dataForReadingAvailable);
```

Tools from Xcode shows that i have leak memory when i a'm allocated object and when i initialized it properties. But why it's happens. All objects is autorealeased, so i think that will not to be such situation.
Thanks.

Comment: are you doing `sqlite3_close(database);`

Comment: no. i open database on start and close on finish

Comment: Does it say *which* object is leaking? (Pro tip: refactoring you code might help find problems easily)

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you overwrite the allocated memory with the new pointer somewhere.

I would replace

```
Article *a = [[[Article alloc] init] autorelease];
```

with

```
Article *a = [[Article alloc] init];
//some code
[a release]; //when you don't need it anymore
```

This is not a good practice to use autorelease much. It can even slow down your app btw in case of many objects.
And the strings like

```
 a.title = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString: colStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

I would replace with

```
 a.title = [NSString stringWithCString:colStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

In this case you also rely on autorelease pool, but it's much simpler.

**EDIT:**
Indeed, your 'Article' allocation is in the do-while loop. 
In string *[array insertObject:a atIndex:0];* your aray retains object and you don't need it anymore, but you rely on autorelease. Analyzer (or what tool you're using) sees, that you placed allocation in the cycle's body without releasing it after each iteration. This way, on the second iteration of the loop, you overwrite your "a" object, loosing the old pointer and leaking memory this way (pool won't find this pointer, since "a" overwritten). Even if you pass your loop only once, the analyzer does not care and gives you a warning.

Comment: thanks for your tips, but i can't rely on garbage collector, because it missing in iOs.

Comment: certainly :), you're right, I meant autorelease pool. This code fits for iOS.

Comment: it is good practice to use autorelease wherever you can. (http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml#Prefer_To_autorelease_At_Time_of_Creation). In this case however where you create a lot of strings you should alloc/init/release because autorelease might not happen until you leave your function and that might be to late.

Comment: "iPhone OS Note: Because on iPhone OS an application executes in a more memory-constrained environment, the use of autorelease pools is discouraged in methods or blocks of code (for example, loops) where an application creates many objects. Instead, you should explicitly release objects whenever possible." (c) (Apple doc)